# Laravel Middleware with other than user()

Tags: php, laravel-5, permissions, frameworks, laravel-middleware

Can we use Middleware with other than User method? I mean... almost in every example or explanations they used `$request->user()` to check user's permissions.

However I want to check user's permission in other table like `$request->category()`. There I want to check if user is Owner of that particular category or not. On this basis, Owner of that category can move around various sections (controllers) with-in that category else he will restricted from that.

Is it possible in Middleware?

============ **HERE IS BETTER EXPLANATIONS** ================

Suppose I own a Group (With Access_Specify> 0:Public, 1:Member, 2:Only Me). Now other user may/may-not subscribe to this group to become member/public to this Group. Beside all this, Group have sub-sections like Albums, Pages, Post etc.

**Now, what I want here** is to check coming user's privileges in **2 tables** before heading in this group. First in Group(via Access_Specify) then Second in GroupMember that if coming user is member of that Group or not.

**Case-Condition:** If Group's Access_Specify set to 1 (Member Access) then only members (+Owner of that group) are allowed to get into that Group.

Group (Access_Specify= 0:Public, 1:Member, 2:Only Me) && GroupMember (UserStatus= 0:PendingForApproval, 1:JoinedAsMember)

if( Above condition is true ){

- Album
- Pages
- Post
- etc..

} else {
 Throw User Out With Error - Exception
}

====================================

In any case I don't want to put this condition in Controllers because... I can't put and check things again and again in every sub-section (controllers). I want the solution like Middleware do, To check user and only then process request.

Comment: The minimal way to do this is via `$request->user()->category` assuming you've got a category relationship defined on user.

Comment: thanks @apokryfos you provide a good and fast logic here. Your solution is acceptable however there is official solution as well describe below by Andréas Lundgren. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello @apokryfos please check my question again, I did edit it again and explain the exact problem I am facing there. thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I may not have understood your requirements properly.

Comment: So any suggestion here?

Comment: If you're suggesting that you need a middleware-like structure that works before every single request, I'd suggest you reconsider, since this will basically trap you in a certain way of implementation. Instead I suggest you specify a [routing group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups) which will allow you to have a shared middleware for all routes in that group. You are already defining routes somewhere so this will not be a very big change.

Answer (score 2):

## Using Gates

For simple stuff, you can write Gates. They are typically defined in an application Service Provider, such as the `AuthServiceProvider`.

### Example

In the `boot()` method of your Service Provider, you can define gates that will check if a given `$user` owns the given `$category`:

#### Defining the Gate

```
Gate::define('update-category', function ($user, $category) {
    return $user->id == $category->user_id;
});
```

The `$user` is a required argument that is automatically passed by Laravel when the Gate is used, and you may pass any additional arguments you need to check against.

#### Using the Gate

When you need to check if the user owns the category, simply call:

```
if (Gate::allows('update-category', $category)) {
    // The current user can update the category...
}
```

or

```
if (Gate::denies('update-category', $category)) {
    // The current user can't update the category...
}
```

You can find more information about Gates in [the official documentation for authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#gates)

## Using Policies

For more advanced authorization, it's probably more suitable to use `Policies`. Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a particular model or resource.

So you could create a `CategoryPolicy` where you create all your checks and register it in the `$policies` array in your `AuthServiceProvider`.

This way you have a handful of options on how and when you would like to call this policy.

- Via the User model
- Via Middleware
- Via Controller helpers
- Via Blade templates

Again, [the official documentation about registering and using Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#creating-policies) does a wonderful job of explaining all of this.

Comment: Thanks @Andréas Lundgren you really provide me good and official solution to my problem. Will use this solution for sure.

Comment: Here is one limitation which I want to Avoid. With Gate/Policies we have to check " Gate::allows/denies " in every controller. Which I never want to. I don't want to go to Controller if User is not authorized like Middleware do. Middleware check user's privileges in Handle method. So is it possible to check before hitting controller. Because I have 8-9 controller under Category and I can not check that in every controller.

Comment: Hello @Andréas Lundgren. please check my question again, I did edit it and explain the exact problem I am facing. thanks in advance.